# Accessing indexPath in a collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview cell which has an image on it and a button below it. Now when I click on this button, I want to load a `tableviewCell` which has on it the image from the collectionview. To achieve this, I did this initially..

```
 func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))
self.photoThumbnail.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]
```

and `photoThumbnail` is defined like so...`var photoThumbnail: UIImageView!` But doing this gives a crash telling `'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value'` So I tried this..

```
let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.collectionView)
let myIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)

self.photoThumbnail.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[(myIndexPath?.row)!]
```

But again, the same crash of `Unexpectedly found nil....` is happening. Any idea as to what could be the issue..?

**EDIT:**
This is the code for `cellForItemAtIndex...`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell

cell.sellButton.tag = indexPath.item

cell.sellButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(SellBtnTapped(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)

return cell
 }
```

Comment: Add your collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView method code

Comment: Also explain which line the error is occurring on.

Comment: you mean the cellForItemAt...? @iPatel

Comment: The crash is happening at self.photoThumbnail.image =... @GaryMakin

Comment: @bws yes, btw look at my ans

Answer (score 0):

It's because you alway get `nil` your indexPath.

Another approach is

in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath` method

set **tag**  of your **cell's** button like

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.item
```

And in `SellBtnTapped` method use below code for get `indexPath`

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0) // set section as you want
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as NSIndexPath) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell
```

Now by use of **cell** you can get image object that is on it or use `self.arrayOfURLImages` to get right image. and do your further stuff.

Comment: It's still crashing...this was what I did...let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0) 

self.photoThumbnail.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]

Comment: Did you set my code in cellForItemAt method ? provide code of this method

Comment: What is your crash log ? what is self.arrayOfURLImages ? put break point on self.photoThumbnail.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row] like and also action: #selector(SellBtnTapped(_:)),for: should be action: #selector(self.SellBtnTapped(_:)),for:

Answer (score 0):

I prefer avoiding tags altogether. I wrote this a while ago and still find it useful.

```
extension UIView {

    var superCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell? {
        if let cell = self as? UICollectionViewCell {
            return cell
        } else {
            return superview?.superCollectionViewCell
        }
    }

    var superCollectionView: UICollectionView? {
        if let collectionView = self as? UICollectionView {
            return collectionView
        } else {
            return superview?.superCollectionView
        }
    }

    var indexPathOfSuperCollectionViewCell: IndexPath? {
        guard let cell = superCollectionViewCell, let collectionView = superCollectionView else { return nil }

        return collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }

}
```

This turns your action into

```
func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let indexPath = sender.indexPathOfSuperCollectionViewCell else {
        print("button has no index path")
        return
    }

    self.photoThumbnail.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Did come up with the solution already without tags, @Jeffery Thomas...but thanks for the answer...Have given an upvote...:)